# UISwitch в UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

Всем привет! 
Есть `tableView`, на нем находится `UISwitch`.
Можно ли при нажатии на клетку изменить состояние UISwitch?

Извините за этот вопрос. Я ещё новичёк в iOS разработке :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно. Используйте метод:
 `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.
Данный метод вызывается при ножатии на ячейку, определите тип ячейки: 
`guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellType else { fatalError("Unexpected cell type") }` и тогда переключите `UISwitch`: `cell.switch.setON = true/false`

Вот примерно так будет выглядеть код:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCellType else {
        fatalError("Unexpected cell type")
    }

    cell.switch.setOn = !cell.switch.isOn
}
```